# Does Scala's specialization compose?

Tags: scala

I was under the impression that specialization composes, but in the following example that doesn't seem to be the case:

```
trait Key [@specialized(Int) A] { 
  def up(k: A): Unit
}

class Test[@specialized(Int) A](key: Key[A], value: A) { 
  key.up(value)
}
```

If I dump this in the Scala REPL with `:javap -v Test`, it seems that the call to `key.up` still boxes the primitive:

```
public Test(Key, java.lang.Object);
  Code:
   Stack=2, Locals=3, Args_size=3
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   putfield    #17; //Field key:LKey;
   5:   aload_0
   6:   aload_2
   7:   putfield    #19; //Field value:Ljava/lang/Object;
   10:  aload_0
   11:  invokespecial   #24; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   14:  aload_0
   15:  getfield    #17; //Field key:LKey;
   18:  aload_0
   19:  getfield    #19; //Field value:Ljava/lang/Object;
   22:  invokeinterface #30,  2; //InterfaceMethod Key.up:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   27:  return
```

So is specialization completely useless for developing generic implementations? In my case, data structures, it would completely undermine the effort to develop concise modular code. So I hope I am missing something...

Comment: Wow, I think you're right--but you need to do it with a def in order to prove it to yourself.  Having a class create a throwaway value isn't a good test.

Comment: The answer of Jed is correct, I think. Nevertheless, I spawned a bit longer thread here, http://groups.google.com/group/scala-user/browse_thread/thread/a0bfb8065771bb53/cb4520960ed90285?show_docid=cb4520960ed90285 which indicates quite a few follow up problems I had with specialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking at the unspecialized version of the class.

When I try I see another class `Test$mcI$sp` that is the specialized compiled version. This is kind of the point, it must create a separate class that is specialized for the primitive you specify.

**Edit**: if looking for the specialized class in the REPL you need to get the full class name. By default, the REPL trims the actual context where the class is stored, so you need to get it by println eg:

```
scala> println(new Test(1).getClass.getName)
$line1.$read$$iw$$iw$Test$mcI$sp

scala> :javap $line1.$read$$iw$$iw$Test$mcI$sp
…
```

Comment: Ok, that's true. `val x = new Test( new Key[ Int ] { def up( v: Int ) {}}, 33 )` gives me indeed `x: Test[Int] = Test$mcI$sp@68dc2d`. However `:javap -v Test$mcI$sp` doesn't find a class by that name.

Comment: I found the specialised version using :javap no problem once I had compiled the class from a source file. In order to load it in the REPL I needed to use the full class name, not the one short one the REPL gives you. See edited answer for details.